# How to filter using hierarchical relationships within Power BI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

I have two columns one being employee and the other being direct manager. The direct managers also show up in the employee column along with their respective direct managers creating a sort of hierarchy. I want to be able to create a filter such that when a manager is selected the result will show a table with all employees that are under that manager not just directly under, but anywhere within the hierarchy.

```
employee direct_manager
1        6
2        3
3        1
4        7
5        4
```

This demonstrates the logic in that we have different layers of hierarchy but the table only shows the direct manager

Comment: sharing some sample data and expected result causes a much more faster answer...

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tabular you need to solve this with modeling.  Either flatten parent-child hierarchies into multiple tables.  See https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/

Or, I think what you're after here, would be to materialize all the indirect "reports-to" relationship pairs in a table.